# HHH000511: The 12.2.0 version for [org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect] is no longer supported

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, ojdbc

When I run my SpringBoot (3.2.2) project it works all fine.
I just got in terminal the following warning:

[HHH000511: The 12.2.0 version for [org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect] is no longer supported, hence certain features may not work properly. The minimum supported version is 19.0.0.](https://stackoverflow.com)

How can I update it? Is it just a depencency to update (version) in POM.xml?
Thank you

My depencency

```
<dependency>
            <!-- Oracle - OJDBC -->
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc11</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

and here my application.properties

```
# JPA Settings
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
```

My Hibernate Core version is: `6.4.1`

Comment: Do you have a com.oracle.database.jdbc dependency in your POM and if so what version are you using? Are you specifying the Hibernate dialect to be used in your application.properties file and if so, what value are you using?

Comment: Hi there, I just updated the question with the informations. Do you have any hints?

Comment: First try commenting out the dialect. Hibernate can usually figure it out based on the connection information.

Comment: I commented it and ran it again but I still got the same warning message in the terminal - do you have any other hints?

Comment: According to the (Spring Boot Dependencies) [https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/dependency-versions.html] Boot should, by default, be bringing in version 21.9.0.0 of the Oracle driver. What version is your Oracle database?

Comment: Hi there, here my Oracle database's version: Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: Oracle 12.2 is rather old, and your support options are limited. You have a couple of options: 1) Upgrade your database 2) downgrade your version of Hibernate or 3) if this a warning, live with it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems like you need to update the oracle database to at least version 19!
but this solution is not feasible for me. Therefore, I resolved this issue by downgrading the hibernate version to 6.2.

```
<properties>
    <hibernate.version>6.2.21.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: Ok ok I understand your point of view. I did a massive update of all the dependencies and wanna keep them up to date. At the moment I've the 6.4.1 version of hibernate and a downgrade it's not planned - but thanks anyway for your input :)

Answer (score 2):

Dialect for older DB's like Oracle 10g are no longer available in hibernate-core. According to [documentation](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/dialects.adoc#community-dialects) older version were moved to hibernate-community-dialects.

So to fix this, add following artifact to project (If you're using maven) I would use version with corresponding version to core

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-community-dialects -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-community-dialects</artifactId>
    <version>6.4.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

And to make this work you need to add info about used dialect. Hence library has changed you need to point to proper dialect class in package org.hibernate.**community**.dialect

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.community.dialect.<here your dialect>
```

Here is configuration for LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean (in case you're using multiple datasources)

```
    @Bean()
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean oracleEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.community.dialect.OracleLegacyDialect"); 
    return builder
            .dataSource(oracleDataSource())
            .packages("com.packages.with.entities.that.will.be.assinged.to.this.emf")
            .persistenceUnit("oracle-PU")
            .properties(properties)
            .build();

}
```

Comment: It works fine but there is another warning. HHH90000026: Oracle10gDialect has been deprecated; use org.hibernate.community.dialect.OracleLegacyDialect instead

Oracle10gDialect is depricated. We should use OracleLegacyDialect

Comment: You should use org.hibernate.community.dialect.OracleLegacyDialect

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Hibernate version 6.0, the legacy dialects like Oracle12cDialect have been moved to a separate artifact, called hibernate-community-dialects. You can add the dependency for this artifact in your project, and set application.properties like this -

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.community.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
```

[hibernate-orm documentation](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/dialects.adoc#community-dialects)

Comment: Hi Taha, thank you for your contributio :) I just tried it and get a big new error: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.community.dialect.Oracle12cDialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]